# Button change position when alert view is showed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am showing an alert on my UITableView.
This is the code

```
-(void)showAlertMaintenance{
 AppDelegate * appDelegate =  (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [RMUniversalAlert showAlertInViewController:self withTitle:nil message:appDelegate.maintenanceStr cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil tapBlock:^(RMUniversalAlert * _Nonnull alert, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
      if(buttonIndex == alert.cancelButtonIndex){

      }
 }];
```

}

The button is a subviews of one section header in my UITableview

```
UIButton *sendInviteCodeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                [sendInviteCodeButton addTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(shareInvitationCode)
                               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [sendInviteCodeButton setTitle:@"招待コードをシェアする" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [sendInviteCodeButton sizeToFit];
                [sendInviteCodeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:116.0f/255.0f blue:52.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                sendInviteCodeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

                sendInviteCodeButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 155.0f, SCREEN_BOUNDS_SIZE_PORTRAIT_WIDTH - 40, 30.0f);

                [sendInviteCodeButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                [sendInviteCodeButton.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
                [sendInviteCodeButton.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
                [sendInviteCodeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [sendInviteCodeButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];

                [invitationView insertSubview:sendInviteCodeButton atIndex:0];
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swlTn.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbKdo.png)

When the alert is showed, the button is being pushed to top left corner of the screen.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you already calculate specific frame for your button, you should remove `[sendInviteCodeButton sizeToFit];`.

Just remove `[sendInviteCodeButton sizeToFit];`

Hope it help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are relying on frames to setup the layout you should have a dedicated UIView subclass for your tableview header.You need to override layoutSubviews method because at this point the header view will have it's own frame correctly set so your relative calculations for subviews (including the button) will make sense. Here's a quick sample code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyTableViewHeader : UIView
@end

@implementation MyTableViewHeader

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //setup button here (omit setting frames)
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    //set the button frame here
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyTableViewHeader *header;
@end

@implementation ViewController
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//You will probably want some logic here
//to decide if you want to display the header
    if (!self.header) {
        self.header = [MyTableViewHeader new];
    }
    return self.header;
}
@end
```

As an alternative you could also setup autolayout for your table header view.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem caused by this

```
[sendInviteCodeButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

`setMasksToBounds` - is a Boolean indicating whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds